# How to fit the Home Screen Wallpaper based on the Emulator Size

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i am programmatically set a Home Screen Wallpaper. It's working fine. How to fit the Home Screen Wallpaper based on the Emulator Size. My Sample Code is here...

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
Bitmap wallpaper = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();           
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(wallpaper, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
try 
{
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Based on the Emulator Size to fit Home Screen Wallpaper, How?
Please reply your comments and results are valuable me. Thanks.

Comment: No Exception. Images does not fit with the Home Screen.

Comment: Ya. It's working also me. But how to fit width and height of the image.